# App cache not working, despite Chrome correctly caching assets

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache

If I load the page while online chrome console logs:

`Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://app.x.com/cache.manifest app.x.com/
Application Cache Checking event app.x.com/
Application Cache Downloading event app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 7) http://app.x.com/public/img/logos/logo.png app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (1 of 7) http://app.x.com/public/img/backgrounds/crowd.png app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (2 of 7) http://app.x.com/public/img/icons/close@2x.png app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (3 of 7) http://app.x.com/public/js/third_party/zepto.js app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (4 of 7) http://app.x.com/public/css/compiled.css app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (5 of 7) http://app.x.com/public/js/compiled.js app.x.com/
Application Cache Progress event (6 of 7) http://app.x.com/ (index)
Application Cache Progress event (7 of 7)  (index)
Application Cache UpdateReady event`

To me this looks fine?

`chrome://appcache-internals` shows:

[image: chrome debug]

However, as soon as I pull the plug on my Ethernet and refresh I get an un-styled page with the following in my console:

[image: nostyles]

For reference my cache.manifest looks like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v52
CACHE:
public/js/third_party/zepto.js
public/js/compiled.js
public/css/compiled.css
public/img/logos/logo.png
public/img/backgrounds/crowd.png
public/img/icons/close@2x.png

NETWORK:
*
```

And I have `AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest` in my .htaccess

Comment: Is there a place where we can test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my fault. I was using css/compiled.css?123 in my header. The ?123 was an ever changing number to bust the cache during development. It seems the application cache treats this as a seperate file so I either have to remove the unique ID or sync it with the application cache for this to work.